# how to apply sorting programatically in gridview headerText?

Tags: gridview

I have `gridview`. in that when get table data using `sqldatasource` in gridview, I can able to sort table data by enabling `AllowSorting="True"` .But when try to get table data using `C#` I couldn't sort that.

here is my screen shot of that output:

[image]

**here is my c# code to retrieve table data:**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=abc\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=mvw;Integrated Security=true;");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  [POID],[SNO],[PartNo],[PartDesc],[Desc2],[OrderNos],[Rate]  ,[Quantity]   ,[units]  ,[Status] ,[RecvOrderNos]    ,[RecvQty]  ,[QtySplitUp]  ,[Remarks] ,[BalQty] FROM [PoToSupplierMasterItems] WHERE POID='" + ddlSelectProcess .SelectedItem.Text+ "'", con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> > > > Hi Dine, as you are binding your grid with the datatable you can easily sort the column of that table then can bind with the gridview. So, what you need to do is :

1) Sort the column of the datatable using linq

 2) bind gridview with the result from the previous step

> > here is the code.Don't forget to mark as Answer and vote,if it satisfies your requirement.

```
  var result = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => r["yourcolumnname"]);
  GridView1.DataSource = result.CopyToDataTable();
```